# Excel: count unique instances across two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that has a column for cell sites and another column for frequency like this:

```
SITE      FREQUENCY
MA1084    687
MA1084    687
MA1084    687
MA1084    4382
MA1084    4382
MA1084    4382
MA1096    4358
MA1096    4358
MA1096    4358
MA1096    687
MA1096    687
MA1096    687
MA1096    4382
MA1096    4382
MA1096    4382
```

I'd like a formula that will add up all the unique combinations of SITE and FREQUENCY. My expected output is below. Basically I want to know how many unique frequencies each cell site has.

```
SITE      FREQUENCY COUNT
MA1084    687       2
MA1084    687       2
MA1084    687       2
MA1084    4382      2
MA1084    4382      2
MA1084    4382      2
MA1096    4358      3
MA1096    4358      3
MA1096    4358      3
MA1096    687       3
MA1096    687       3
MA1096    687       3
MA1096    4382      3
MA1096    4382      3
MA1096    4382      3
```

I can do this with a pivot table but am looking for a formula based solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you considered a pivot table? I believe it could do this quite easily ?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a helper column. While not always ideal, it depends on how you need the output displayed.
Assuming `Site` and `Frequency` are in columns A and B, then in the concatenate column type: `=A2&B2`. Then in the `Count` column type: `=COUNTIF(C:C,C2)`. Then you get the following:

```
SITE    FREQUENCY   Concatentae COUNT
MA1084  687 MA1084687   3
MA1084  687 MA1084687   3
MA1084  687 MA1084687   3
MA1084  4382    MA10844382  3
MA1084  4382    MA10844382  3
MA1084  4382    MA10844382  3
MA1096  4358    MA10964358  3
MA1096  4358    MA10964358  3
MA1096  4358    MA10964358  3
```

Comment: Helper columns are often useful, but this answer does not give the results that the question asks for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **array formula**:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$16=A2,MATCH(B$2:B$16,B$2:B$16,0)),ROW(B$2:B$16)-MIN(ROW(B$2:B$16))+1),1))
```

Copy down as required.

Adjust the ranges to suit, though be sure not to make them too arbitrarily large (and certainly don't reference entire columns!), since array formulas calculate over all cells passed to them, including those which are technically beyond the last-used cells in the range.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

With a helper column:

- Set `D2` to `=IF(COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,B2)=1,1,0)`. 
  This checks whether any previous rows match the Site and Frequency
  on this row. 
  If this is the first, evaluate to 1; else, 0. 
  So this marks the first row of every group with a 1.
- Set `C2` to `=SUMIFS(D$2:D$16,A$2:A$16,A2)`. 
  This adds the Column D values for rows that have the same Site as this row. 
  That gives a count of the distinct frequencies associated with this site.

Then select `C2` and `D2` and drag/fill down.
          [image: spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer based on Excel 365:

Formula for cell `C2` (copy down as needed):

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(IF(A:A=A2,B:B,"")))-1
```

- `IF(A:A=A2,B:B,"")` list all the items where SITE is *this* SITE and show blank for everything else.
- `UNIQUE(IF(~))` filters for just the unique items in that list.
- `ROWS(UNIQUE(~))` counts the number of rows in that unique list.
- `...-1` because the value of `""` will still show up as an empty row and you don't want to include that result.

[image: Screenshot]