# Calculate Distinct Values Based On 4 Conditions (Excel Formula)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table structure as per below:

```
    [A]    [B]    [C]    [D]    [E]
[1] Dog    Big    2018   02     123
[2] Dog    Big    2018   02     123
[3] Cat    Small  2019   05     123
[4] Dog    Big    2018   02     124
[5] Cat    Small  2019   05     123
```

Column [E] contains important duplicate values. The task is to filter on column [A], [B], and [C] (ignore [D]) and find distinct values on each dataset based on column [E].

**Step 1: identify and count occurrences of unique combinations of columns [A], [B], [C] by doing a COUNTIFS**

```
=COUNTIFS(
 A:A,A1,
 B:B,B1,
 C:C,C1,
)
```

This shows me for:

row 1 = 3

row 2 = 3

row 3 = 2

row 4 = 3

row 5 = 2

**Step 2: for the unique combinations identified in step 1, count the unique combinations of those plus column [E]**

row 1 = should be 2

row 2 = should be 2

row 3 = should be 1

row 4 = should be 2

row 5 = should be 1

These results are because there are two unique combinations in columns A, B, and C: {Dog, Big, 2018} and {Cat, Small, 2019}.  {Dog, Big, 2018} is associated with two unique values in column E and {Cat, Small, 2019} is associated with one unique value in column E.

Comment: Do you just need to know how many there are, or do you also want to end up with a list of unique values?

Comment: How many there are, already sorted - see my answer

Comment: Can you clarify your step 2 results?  By my figuring rows 3 through 5 should have results of 2,1,2, respectively.  I can't make sense of how you get 1,2,1.  The question wording describes the col E filtering as a continuation of the same pattern; col E sounds like it is just a 4th criterion.  But you appear to be handling it as something different.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Since col E row 4 is unique, how can it be a filter, along with anything else, and produce a count higher than 1?

Comment: First you filter on 3 columns and after that you find the distinct values in that dataset

Answer (score 1):

Using SUMPRODUCT with COUNTIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$5=A1)*($B$1:$B$5=B1)*($C$1:$C$5=C1)/(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$5,A1,$B$1:$B$5,B1,$C$1:$C$5,C1,$E$1:$E$5,$E$1:$E$5)+($A$1:$A$5<>A1)+($B$1:$B$5<>B1)+($C$1:$C$5<>C1)))
```

The COUNTIFS divides the total count by the whether each row matches then sums them.  So for example Row 1 ends up with `SUMPRODUCT({1,1,0,1,0}/{2,2,2,1,2})` which then resolves to `SUMPRODUCT({.5,.5,0,1,0})` or `2`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorted with the help of:

[Excel: count unique instances across two columns](https://superuser.com/questions/995042/excel-count-unique-instances-across-two-columns)

and

https://professor-excel.com/number-unique-records/

**POTENTIAL ANSWER (WORKING):**

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$1:$A$5=A1,IF($B$1:$B$5=B1,IF($C$1:$C$5=C1,MATCH($E$1:$E$5,$E$1:$E$5,0)))),ROW($E$1:$E$5)-MIN(ROW($E$1:$E$5))+1),1))
```

Comment: Don't forget to CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER! :)